# Aligning equations using align

Tags: align

I want to align these equations. I don't think they are prefectly aligned. My code :

```
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}_{2}[S_{3}](HH) = p S_{3}(HHH) + (1-p) S_{3}(HHT) \label{eqn1}\\
    \mathbb{E}_{2}[S_{3}](HT) = p S_{3}(HTH) + (1-p) S_{3}(HTT) \label{eqn2}\\
    \mathbb{E}_{2}[S_{3}](TH) = p S_{3}(THH) + (1-p) S_{3}(THT) \label{eqn3}\\
    \mathbb{E}_{2}[S_{3}](TT) = p S_{3}(TTH) + (1-p) S_{3}(TTT) \label{eqn4}.
\end{align}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). You just need to specify the alignment points. That is, use `&=` instead of `=`.  This will align the equal signs. If you _also_ want to have the `+` signs aligned then use the `\begin{alignat}{3}` and `\end{alignat}` instead and replace the `=` with `&=`, and replace the `+` with `&&+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 3 options:

1. Regular `align` with the alignment around `=`.
2. A right-left alignment around `=` as well as a left-alignment around `+`.
3. An alignment around `=` and `+`, with the terms centre-aligned (using `\eqmakebox[<tag>]` from [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}_2[S_3](HH) &= p S_3(HHH) + (1 - p) S_3(HHT) \\
  \mathbb{E}_2[S_3](HT) &= p S_3(HTH) + (1 - p) S_3(HTT) \\
  \mathbb{E}_2[S_3](TH) &= p S_3(THH) + (1 - p) S_3(THT) \\
  \mathbb{E}_2[S_3](TT) &= p S_3(TTH) + (1 - p) S_3(TTT)
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \mathbb{E}_2[S_3](HH) &= p S_3(HHH) &&+ (1 - p) S_3(HHT) \\
  \mathbb{E}_2[S_3](HT) &= p S_3(HTH) &&+ (1 - p) S_3(HTT) \\
  \mathbb{E}_2[S_3](TH) &= p S_3(THH) &&+ (1 - p) S_3(THT) \\
  \mathbb{E}_2[S_3](TT) &= p S_3(TTH) &&+ (1 - p) S_3(TTT)
\end{alignat}

\begin{align}
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{$\mathbb{E}_2[S_3](HH)$} &= \eqmakebox[pS]{$p S_3(HHH)$} + \eqmakebox[1-pS]{$(1 - p) S_3(HHT)$} \\
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{$\mathbb{E}_2[S_3](HT)$} &= \eqmakebox[pS]{$p S_3(HTH)$} + \eqmakebox[1-pS]{$(1 - p) S_3(HTT)$} \\
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{$\mathbb{E}_2[S_3](TH)$} &= \eqmakebox[pS]{$p S_3(THH)$} + \eqmakebox[1-pS]{$(1 - p) S_3(THT)$} \\
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{$\mathbb{E}_2[S_3](TT)$} &= \eqmakebox[pS]{$p S_3(TTH)$} + \eqmakebox[1-pS]{$(1 - p) S_3(TTT)$}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```